# How to get result in form component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I'm new in react. I have this code to insert data on database this code use react query

```js
import { API_ENDPOINTS } from '@framework/utils/api-endpoints';
import http from '@framework/utils/http';
import { useMutation } from 'react-query';

export interface ReviewFormValues {
  title: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  cookie: string;
  description: string;
  product_id: number | string;
  rating: number;
}

async function addReview(input: ReviewFormValues) {
  const { data } = await http.post(API_ENDPOINTS.REVIEWS, input);
  return {
    data: data,
  };
}
export const useAddReviewMutate = () => {
  return useMutation((input: ReviewFormValues) => addReview(input), {
    onSuccess: (data: any) => {
      console.log(data); // see returned data successfully 
      return data; // trying to return the data to catch it.
    },
    onError: (data) => {
      console.log(data, 'Checkout error response');
    },
  });
};
```

and in my form component when submit I need to get the data to show it and clear the form.

```js
function onSubmit(values: ReviewFormValues) {
    const res = addReview(values);
    console.log(res); // undefined 
    if (isSuccess) { 
      console.log(res); // not run
      console.log('success');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay there're two solutions

the first one is to invalidate the query in React Query whenever the request is ok and this will force React Query to do a refetch

and the last one is to call a fetcher method whenever the isSuccess is true, this can be handled by making a Boolean flag that's by default false, and when the request is ok, this boolean flag will be changed to true and to do a refetch you'll need to add this flag to a useEffect dep and run the fetcher method inside of its callback. or you can make a condition that does the same

I still recommend the first way because it's much easier and more convenient.

the code that demonstrates the first solution

```js
/**
  adding "invalidateQueries" method inside of onSuccess callback will automatically invalidate the data which will force react query to do a refetch.
*/
const mutation = useMutation({
  mutationFn: someMethod,
  onSuccess: () => {
    queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['the key of your query'] })
  },
})
```

Comment: Could show me the code of your solution?

Comment: I edited the answer with a code that demonstrates the first solution.

Comment: Thank you for answer but this not what I looking for.